# gulp dest.on is not a function when replacing

Tags: javascript, html, replace, compiler-errors, gulp

I am trying to replace characters in a compiled html file.

```
function watcherpages() {
return gulp.src(['src/pages/**/*.html', '!src/pages/archive/**/*.html'])
    .pipe(panini({
        root: 'src/pages',
        layouts: 'src/layouts',
        partials: 'src/partials',
        helpers: 'src/helpers',
        data: 'src/data'
    }))
    .pipe(inky())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('watch'))
    .pipe($.replace, '&lt;', '<');
```

}

but the last line of code gives me the following error

```
14:00:01] TypeError: dest.on is not a function
at Pumpify.Readable.pipe (\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:564:8)
at watcherpages (\gulpfile.js:84:10)
at bound (domain.js:301:14)
at runBound (domain.js:314:12)
at asyncRunner (\node_modules\async-done\index.js:55:18)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

Comment: Don't you need parentheses like .pipe($.replace( '&lt;', '<'));  [and then you will need another gulp.dest pipe after the replace pipe to save the results somewhere].  Note the parentheses right after replace and another at the end.

Comment: @Mark can you leave a seperate comment so i could accept it. Thank you so much, the parentheses were missing and you just saved my day ahahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line below you are missing some parentheses:

```
.pipe($.replace, '&lt;', '<');
```

should be

```
.pipe($.replace( '&lt;', '<'));
```

[and you will ultimately need to save these changes later in your pipeline]